# How to grow a popover controller

Tags: swift, xcode, ipad, uipopovercontroller, mac-catalyst

I have a popover controller in my app for iPad and Mac (using mac catalyst) and I'm trying to figure out how to grow the height of the popover when it's already presented. I've been searching everywhere on how to do this but everything I find is about setting the size before presenting but not after.

**While the pop-up is presenting, there's a button in it that should grow the height by 100-150 pixels, but I can not figure out how**

Can anyone please help me with this? Thank you in advance!

Here's my popover presenting code:

```
func openView(sourceView: UIView?, sourceRect: CGRect?) {
    let vc = ViewControllerA()

    //Try popover
    if let sourceView = sourceView,
        let sourceRect = sourceRect {
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
            
            if let popover = vc.popoverPresentationController {
                vc.preferredContentSize = return CGSize(width: 390, height: 390)
                vc.presentationController?.delegate = self

                popover.sourceView = sourceView
                popover.sourceRect = sourceRect
                popover.permittedArrowDirections = [.up, .left]

                self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                return
            }
        }


    //present it normally if there's no source view
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve

    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change a size of your presented controller in popover view you should modify its `preferredContentSize` property:

```swift
@IBAction func showPopover(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Create controller
    guard let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Popover") else {
        return
    }
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    controller.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
    
    // Configure popover
    guard let popover = controller.popoverPresentationController else {
        return
    }
    popover.permittedArrowDirections = .up
    popover.sourceView = self.view
    popover.sourceRect = sender.frame
    popover.delegate = self
    present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
    // Change height after 3 secs
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
        controller.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 400)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for writing! How can I change it from inside the “controller”? There will be a button inside the controller that should grow the height of the popover only when they press the button. So a timer can not work and should the changing size code be inside the controller?

Comment: @fphelp it's just a sample how to change. You should change `preferredContentSize ` of your controller where you need it in your code so if the button handler inside your controller you can set it directly: `self.preferredContentSize = ...` etc.

Comment: Oh perfect, that worked! Can't believe I didn't try that before! Thanks!